# Python data frame Export to csv with Quotation marks (")

Tags: python, export-to-csv

How to export python dataframe to csv with double quotes. I have tried with below code but its not coming in output file. I need results like  "column1","column2",column3"... Please help.

```
exportPath=exportPath+'\\data2Upload.csv'
header=['Country','Indicator','Unit','Frequency','Date','Value']
data.to_csv(exportPath,columns=header,sep=',',quotechar='"',index=False)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell pandas to quote everything by default using the `csv.QUOTE_ALL` property:

```
data.to_csv(exportPath, columns=header,sep=",",quotechar='"',index=False,
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Official Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL

Comment: Thanks. Note: csv is required: `import csv`.