# Quote str's; unquote float's in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

After processing the file **unclean.csv**

```
Date,Wave,Wavelength
2019-08-28,Theta,0.112358472
2019-08-27,Eta,571.5499015
2019-08-27,Lambda,286.4175921
2019-08-26,Iota,0.220237736
```

with the code

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

myfile = ('path/to/'
          'unclean.csv')

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(myfile))
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(myfile))

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df[['Wave']] = df[['Wave']].astype(str)
df[['Wavelength']] = df[['Wavelength']].astype(float)

df.to_csv('clean.csv',
          float_format='%g',
          index=False,
          quotechar='"',
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

I get the output **clean.csv**

```
"Date","Wave","Wavelength"
"2019-08-28","Theta","0.112358"
"2019-08-27","Eta","571.55"
"2019-08-27","Lambda","286.418"
"2019-08-26","Iota","0.220238"
```

where everything is quoted, despite that I have specifically set the type of the column `Wavelength` to `float` and that as a parameter to `to_csv` I asked for quoting just the nonnumeric fields.

How can I quote the strings and keep the numbers unquoted?

Many discussions (e.g.:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147058/pandas-to-csv-output-quoting-issue),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719802/python-data-frame-export-to-csv-with-quotation-marks),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541302/pandas-to-csv-with-quoting-3-quote-nonnumeric-doesnt-work),
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960346/how-to-add-quotes-to-every-element-in-non-numeric-column-of-a-dataframe-save))
suggest that `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` should do it.

Using `pandas==0.24.2` and `unicodecsv==0.14.1`, both from `anaconda-project==0.8.2`.

**Comment**

Valentino's answer pinpoints the problem, but I know of no alternative to `float_format='%g'`

```
"Date","Wave","Wavelength"
"2019-08-28","Theta",0.11235847199999999
"2019-08-27","Eta",571.5499014999999
"2019-08-27","Lambda",286.41759210000004
"2019-08-26","Iota",0.22023773600000002
```

to avoid introducing a sprinkling of `999999` and `0000001`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [pandas to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) docs:

> quoting : optional constant from csv module
>   Defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL. **If you have set a float_format then floats are converted to strings and thus csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC will treat them as non-numeric.**

(emphasis is mine)

Just drop the `float_format='%g'` parameter and your float will not be quoted.

**EDIT**

If you need to format the floats there is no direct way to achieve what you want using `to_csv` parameters, to my knowledge.
But you still can "fake" the format by yourself.

```
#make a new dataframe with formatted strings
ddf = df.applymap(lambda x : '{:g}'.format(x) if isinstance(x, float) else '"{}"'.format(x))

#write the new dataframe to csv, now using QUOTE_NOTE because we already added quote characters where needed
ddf.to_csv('clean.csv',
      index=False,
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

The `clean.csv` file will look like:

```
Date,Wave,Wavelength
"2019-08-28 00:00:00","Theta",0.112358
"2019-08-27 00:00:00","Eta",571.55
"2019-08-27 00:00:00","Lambda",286.418
"2019-08-26 00:00:00","Iota",0.220238
```

Comment: Great explanation. I updated the question to illustrate why I really need to keep the float_format as it is.